# How to ensure user enters characters into textbox?

Tags: javascript, keyup

This field requires characters to be input into the textbox, however right now, a user can enter one character and still move on. I want to create an alert message that will pop up if the user only enters one character, and then once they click okay, it should take them back to that same textbox until they enter the second character. How can I accomplish this?

```
function validatemycode() {
    $('datagroup').on('keyup', 'input[id^="datagroup_1"]', function () {
        if (!this.value){
            alert('You must enter two characters.');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: you can use `this.value.length`  to check how many characters have been entered

Comment: Are you sure you want this? It would make a pretty poor user experience. You type 1 char and you get an alert saying you should type 2 chars before you even had a chance to do so…

Comment: You can use `blur` instead of `keyup`. It will fire only when focus moves away from the input.

Comment: Totally agree with @Thijs . It would be better to use a `blur` event (to check the length of the value after the user moved out from the input) and just to make sure the validation runned, check again in the form submit

Comment: why do you use js when you can use the html pattern? "<input pattern=".{2,}"   required>"

Comment: With focus. JAVASCRIPT: document.getElementById("myAnchor").focus(); JQUERY: $("#target").focus();

Comment: Please don't update the question with the modified answer, a reference to the original is required. Simply accept the correct answer.

Comment: Do not force user to return to the field unless all other controls on the page require filling it first. They might want to fill the form in whatever order they want.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve better usability, you shouldn't show an alert dialog for errors like this. You should instead tell the user that 2 characters minimum is required, and mark the field as invalid (e.g. red border and a warning text) and prevent form submission until it's valid.

But to answer directly to your question, you should rather use `blur` and check the length of the input text.

```
function validatemycode() {
    $('datagroup').on('blur', 'input[id^="datagroup_1"]', function () {
        if (this.value.length < 2){
            $('datagroup').focus();
            alert('You must enter two characters.');
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer. Note that you will run into trouble if you have several fields with the same requirement.

Comment: Oops, sorry there was a bug. I fixed the `if (...)` in the answer.

Comment: What's the HTML code for the actual input? You need to have a correct selector inside the jquery bit `$('...')`

Comment: Seeing the HTML would help solving the issue

Comment: fixed by changing $('datagroup').focus(); to $(this).focus();